# Assign click-event on a new element in the event itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a new element and assign this element the same event for onclick, which it has created it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J9MLP/)

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $('.sub').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        counter++;
        $div = $(this); // makes more sense in the original code
        $div.append('<div class="sub" title="subsub">subsub' + counter + '</div>');
        //$div.find('.sub').click // <-- ?????
    });
});
```

In my demo I want to create a new subsub for every sub, which was clicked. Than I want to add the same click event to the new subsub element.

Could anyone help me with this?
I've found nothing for this problem. Maybe I don't have the correct keywords for google or SO :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use **event Delegation**

```
 $(document).on('click', '.sub', function(event){
```

Your click events seem to be working correctly at this point,because you are using `append` which actually nests the `new div` inside the div that is clicked. Try using `after` and the functionality breaks.

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '.sub', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        counter++;
        $div = $(this); // makes more sense in the original code
        $div.after('<div class="sub" title="subsub">subsub' + counter + '</div>');
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/J9MLP/2/)**

Comment: works like a charm. your first version works perfect for my problem. it is correct, that i want to nest the new div in the clicked div.

Comment: cool.. Just wanted to check if you really want to nest them as the initial structure was different.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create proper elements instead :

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $('.sub').on('click', doStuff);

    function doStuff(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        counter++;
        var $div = $(this),
            $sub = $('<div />', {'class':'sub',
                                 title  : 'subsub',
                                 text   : 'subsub' + counter,
                                 on     : {
                                            click : doStuff
                                          }
                                }
        );

        $div.append($sub);
    }
});
```

Comment: nice answer. this was my first idea of it. i had no idea of the way your're creating a new element via jquery. thanks for it